# Implementing BroadcastReceiver inside JobService

Tags: java, android, broadcast, job-scheduling, receiver

I am working on an application that uses JobService. Now, in my app i want to reschedule the Broadcast receiver that is working in the background. So, i want to know if i can implement BroadcastReceiver inside JobService so that it can restart after several times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. If it's background service, use [PowerManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html) and WakeLock to keep CPU running while you you restart your service. Btw why you need to restart it?

EDIT:

if you want to keep alive your service return `START_STICKY` in your `onStartCommand()`

Comment: Because. some times system kills background service.....when memory is low....i want to rescedule it after sometime so, even if service is killed by system It autometically restart it...

Comment: If you want  to keep service running and restart it if it's killed `return START_STICKY` in your service's `onStartCommand()` method.

Comment: I have already done that and also implement 'BOOT_COMPLETED' but, somehow system kills services. when memory is low

Comment: Yes it does kill it, but it will restart it then memory is available.

Comment: Is your service defined in Manifest?